# Can we use our own map in android?

Tags: android, dictionary

Can we use our own map(Like our house map) and then use GPS to show where we are in the map?
If it is possible then how to do it?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad and could almost certainly be answered with 'yes'.

Comment: Agree... Sure this works... But only if you build your own logics around your own kind of maps. A other idea (not recommended!) would be to place your map as a overlay on for example the google map. So you could use the standard map functions available through the google api for markers. But as I allready said. This is not recommended!

Comment: @FlyBy why is it not recommended? Why?

Comment: Guys!!! I Just need map of my house... and make an app according to it..

Comment: Well. Sure. This would work and would be relative easy to do. I, for myself, think it is not recommended, because google let you access so much good map infos with their collected data. I am pretty sure that a "own" map doesn't provide so much, so good and so up-to-date data like google maps does. This would be kind of a downgrade of the qualitiy a google map could give to you.

Comment: @Coder_sLay: Just use a overlay and position it where your your house is...

Comment: @FlyBy the reason why i want to create acustom map is that i want the map of my house...It should show the bedroom,kitchen,swimming pool and all... So i need to make my own map...:D

Comment: Inside your house the gps signal won't be good enough (IF you get one) to tell you a position that is exact enough to show your position for certain rooms. In the end you will only get a position from the network instead of gps. The accuracy of network positions (50 to 200 meters) isn't good enough to show up certain rooms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do anything you want, but if you are asking if there is an easy way to do this, no.

You would have to produce a scale drawing, then map the pixel space to the scale of the image, know what geopoints represented the corners of your map, then project that onto your scaled display image.

Some open source products use tiled images similar to google maps, but they use OSM data, I suppose if you were dedicated you could use that and turn your map into tiles but I would think for your purposes it would be easier to do this your self.

You might check the google code repository etc. and other open source venues and see if anyone has done anything similar to this.

Also the best accuracy you are going to get is about 2m, and certainly not indoors (if you got a signal at all)